# Continuously differentiable functions

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $f, g,$ be $  C^2$ functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$ F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},  F(x,y) = f(x+g(y))$

Check that $(D_1F)(D_{12}F)=(D_2F)(D_{11}F)$

I know how to compute first derivatives of F:

$D_1F = D_1f(x+g(y))\times 1 $

$D_2F = D_1f(x+g(y))\times g'(y)$

but I tend to get stuck on the second derivatives. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please include all relevant hypotheses (how smooth are these functions?). You have a typo in line 2.

Comment: Now I'm not even sure about the derivatives I calculated, are they correct?

Comment: looks correct. Why don't you continue in the same way with second derivatives? You may just write $f'$ instead of $D_1 f$.

Comment: So then do I get $ D_{11} = f''(x+g(y)) \times 1$? And for $ D_{12} =D_1[f'(x+g(y)) \times g'(y)]$ ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So my next steps will be to use chain rule for the product $f'(x+g(y)) \times g'(y) $ But I will try this tomorrow.Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So I followed the hints and this is what I got:

$ D_{11} = f''(x+g(y))$

$D_{12}=f''(x+g(y))g'(y)$

so then if we combine everything

$D_2FD_{11}= f'(x+g(y))g'(y)f''(x+g(y))$

$D_1FD_{12} = f''(x+g(y))g'(y)f'(x+g(y))$

and we see they are indeed equal.